# Как правильно написать ScrollTop в FireFox?

Tags: javascript, firefox

Всем привет!
Следующий код работает в Гугл Хроме:

```
$('div.full-text img').click(function() {
            var $loc = $(this).attr("src");
            $("#overlay_container img").attr("src", $loc);
            var $scrollnumber = $("body").scrollTop();
            $(".overlay").show().css('top', $scrollnumber-150);
            return false;
        });
```

Как переписать или же дополнить этот код чтобы заработала в Мозиле?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $scrollnumber = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Вот здесь поменял на window, теперь и в гугл хроме и в мозиле все работает.